# Some questions of tile group header template - get value of group header, change automatically group header at editing

Tags: wpf, header, devexpress, tile

I'm using devexpress TileLayoutControl. I'm trying to custom the header template of group.

I do this :

```
<devexpress:TileLayoutControl.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:EditableTextBoxHeader Texte="{Binding Path=???}" TexteColor="Black" FontSize="{StaticResource TaillePoliceGrande}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                </DataTemplate>      
</devexpress:TileLayoutControl.GroupHeaderTemplate>
```

1) i'm using a user control, but i don't know how to get the text value of group header ?

2) if i use my own control for the header, if i set   AllowGroupHeaderEditing="True", is the tile where I change the group header will be update automatically ? Or I need to use the "default" header template to do this ?

Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my questions :

1) it's **TemplateBinding Content** to get the value

```
<devexpress:TileLayoutControl.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:EditableTextBoxHeader Texte="{TemplateBinding Content}" TexteColor="Black" FontSize="{StaticResource TaillePoliceGrande}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                </DataTemplate>      
</devexpress:TileLayoutControl.GroupHeaderTemplate>
```

2) i used **the default textbox in template** and added my own others control in it.